# Permission Denial when trying to send CSV file to email, requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-permissions, android-fileprovider

I am generating a CSV file from data pulled from Firebase and then trying to attach it to an email (and about two weeks ago this code worked!), but I keep getting the same error of a toast message saving the file cannot be attached and the following error in my log cat when I perform this task now:

```
2020-08-20 17:05:43.355 11147-11268/com.example.cpd E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri content://com.example.cpd.provider/external/MyCPDAudit.csv from pid=30180, uid=1000 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
```

My code to generate the email Intent is as follows

```
            //INTENT TO SEND USER EMAIL
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
            //SETS THE USERS EMAIL AS THE RECIPIENT EMAIL ADDRESS
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{user.getEmail()});
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Audit Profile");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Thank you for using CPD Journal to build your CPD Audit Profile. Please see the attached file for your records.");
            emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

            File file = new File(csv);
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(SavedAudit.this, "com.example.cpd.provider", file);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

            //USER CAN SELECT HOW THEY WANT TO SHARE THE CSV FILE
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Pick an email provider"));
```

I have the following permissions in my Android Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

File provider in Manifest is

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.cpd.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

My file paths are

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

As per the logcat, I have tried exporting the provider in my Manifest file, but this crashes the app on launch.

I have tried adding the following two lines with my email Intent, but this results in the same log cat error:

```
String packageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
grantUriPermission(packageName, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

My csv and uri log as follows

```
2020-08-20 18:03:30.969 20914-20914/com.example.cpd D/TAG: csv = /storage/emulated/0/MyCPDAudit.csv
2020-08-20 18:03:30.974 20914-20914/com.example.cpd D/TAG: uri = content://com.example.cpd.provider/external/MyCPDAudit.csv
```

However, I'm not sure if I'm using this grantUriPermission method correctly by calling it like this - any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Please show the value of `csv` and `uri.toString()`.

Comment: Show the provider definition in manifest. An show your paths xml file too.

Comment: I have updated my question to include all of these now - thank you for looking at this for me

Comment: Are you on Android Q/10 ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using android 10/sdk 29

Comment: Under Android 10 you cannot have this path  /storage/emulated/0/MyCPDAudit.csv. So start telling why you could. And how did you place that file there? Have you checked if the file exists? How?

Comment: Ah I think I know what might be causing the issue - to create the path for the file I used the deprecated `String csv = (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyCPDAudit.csv");` and in my Manifest file set `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` as a temporary fix. The code I have was working a few weeks ago because I was sending test emails with the attachment and I still have these in my sent box with the csv file that I can download and view. Just not sure what has changed since then to make the code break.

Comment: That extra line in the manifest should give you access. For me your code looks ok.

Comment: @blackapps I've solved the issue now by changing the path for the file to `final File csv = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "/MyCPDAudit.csv");` Thank you for looking over this for me.